# Can we use a parameter in a pl sql subprogram other than in where clause

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Can we use the parameters in a pl sql subprogram other than in where clause

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO.  Please read [ask], and update your question with some relevant code or something. Short answer, yes.

Comment: question would have been a bit more clear.

Comment: A PL/SQL subprogram doesn't even need to have SQL in it. What do you think `dbms_output.put_line('Hello, world')` does with its parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Once you declare the variables in a PLSQL program, you can use it anywhere in the program. See below an example

```
DECLARE
   var   VARCHAR2 (100);                                  -- Variable declared
BEGIN
   var := 'My name is jack';                              -- Assigning a string to the varibale

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (var);                            -- Displaying it.


   SELECT 'My name is Mack' INTO var FROM DUAL;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (var);
END;
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you surely can.

```
Create or replace procedure test(a_param_1 in int, a_param_2 out int)
as
v_var int;
begin
dbms_output.put_line(a_param);--you can print the param 
v_var := a_param ;-- you can assign it to some other value
a_param_2 := 1; --Out parameter can be assigned a value.
end;
```